# Несколько кнопок Like на одной странице

Tags: facebook-widgets

Всем привет.  
На сайте делаю музыкальный альбом. Решил для каждого трека сделать кнопокчи "Мне нравится".
С кнопочкой от ВКонтакте всё очень просто:

```
<div id="vk_like_[id]"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like_[id]", { type: "mini", pageTitle: 'Заголовок', pageDescription: 'Мне понравился трек [trackname]'}, [track_id]);
</script>
```

То есть, в чём смысл, в цикле можно создать любое количество контейнеров с уникальным `ID`, и в том же цыкле генерировать JS, передавать `like` виджету `ID` нужного нам контейнера и в конце мы указываем 32-битное число (в нашем случае это `track_id`), которое и делает множество кнопок `like` на одной странице уникальными.

В FaceBook'е же, я что-то не могу разобраться, как это сделать. Кто уже делал подобное, не в курсе, как это сделать? 
Спасибо. :)

Comment: а если сайт динамический и на всех кнопках FB->like постах одинакова считает кликнутых?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понимаю, то достаточно один раз на странице добавить [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Пишут, что идеально это сделать сразу после открывающегося <body>.
А дальше можно сколько угодно добавлять кнопок:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myurl" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Где соответственно http://myurl - это урлик на каждый ваш трек.

[Подробнее](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Дополнение.

Чтобы отделить треки на странице, делайте якоря через id. Например,

```
<div id="track1">Тут Ваш трек1</div>
<div id="track2">Тут Ваш трек2</div>
```

А в кнопках используйте http://myurl#track1 и http://myurl#track2.
Правда сам не проверял, не знаю как сработает.

Comment: у меня все треки находятся на одной странице  
www.myurl.com/home/audios то есть, трек в отдельности ссылку не имеет. Ну разве что прямую ссылку на сам mp3 файл.

Comment: да, я тоже самое сказал - один в один :)

Comment: Ozim, не спорю, у людей иногда сходятся мысли. Я чуть позже ответил, но когда начинал отвечать Вашего ответа еще не было.
Eugene, смотри дополнение, если получится отпишись, пожалуйста, для будущих поколений ;)

Comment: Да, работает. :)

Answer (score 2):

это после бади

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

это в цикл, подставляя в data-href нужную ссылку

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="site.ru" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: Хм, а если у меня все треки расположены на одной странице?

Comment: Какая разница. Есть параметр **data-href** - пихаете в него нужный url и все.

Comment: @eugene, а что тогда должно нравиться людям? i like - это фишка, которая показывает, что кому то нравится какой то url, вот и сформируйте свои ссылки, чтобы они могли нравиться.

Да впишите прямо ссылку на файл.

Comment: ну ок. "Мне нравится" ВКонтакте можно указать какой - либо текст. то есть, что именно мне понравилось допустим. Но все эти кнопки могут вести на одну и ту же ссылку. а вот там уже список треков. и на против каждого трека есть кнопочка "Мне нравится" и у КАЖДОЙ кнопочки есть счётчик. ну и всё. мне это и надо. а в ФБ надо указывать на каждую отдельную ссылку я так понял, чтобы счётчик считал правильно.

Comment: блин! нравится **не может** участок кода на странице! нравиться может ссылка! сделайте ссылки http://site.ru/track.mp3 и будут у вас разные данные на каждом треке, если они у вас идут только списком, а если у каждого трека есть еще и своя страница - тогда делаете ссылку на эту страницу, например http://site.ru/trach.mp3.html

что тут не ясно?

Comment: Не нервничайте. )  
Всё очень прекрасно работает. В конце ссылки достаточно указать `#audio_id=[id]`.  

И как это НЕ может нравится что-то отдельное на странице? Вы ВКонтакте сидите? Или на ФБ? там каждый комментарий может понравиться.

Comment: Это значит, что у каждого комментария есть свой url - он может формироваться из id, из персональной страницы комментария - да из чего угодно, но факт фактом - у каждого свой url в параметре data-href

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно - нужно делать их в фреймах. Пример можно посмотреть на http://droidnews.ru/. Но вот только такое добро так хорошо иногда тормозит страницу, что хочется этих горе программистов послать подальше, а сайт закрыть.

Comment: Не знаю, как ФБ, а вот ВК кнопочки не тормозят страницу.  
Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: фреймы это не очень хорошо, тем более если их будет много на странице

Comment: Кнопки ВК ещё как тормозят страницу. Но это проявляется, если там не зарегистрирован.